# Reordering similar elements within an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap

I have a requirement where I need to group similar elements together within an original list.

For example:

I/P array:

`[1, 2, 3, A1, B1, 4, B2, 5, 6, C1, B3, B4, 7, 8, 9, 10, A2, A3, 11, 12, A4, C2, D1]`

Now I would like to group the elements starting with an alphabet such that all the elements belonging to a specific alphabet are together and would be placed right after the first occurrence of that alphabet.

O/P array:

`[1, 2, 3, A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4, 4, 5, 6, C1, C2, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, D1]`

One trivial solution that I came up with is to maintain a HashMap denoting the alphabets and its elements, `Map<Character, Queue<Element>>` and do the following steps:

1. Iterate through the list and if an alphabet is encountered, do one of the following:

   1.1 If the alphabet doesn't exist in the map, add it to the map with an empty queue, `map.put('A', new LinkedList<>())`

   1.2 If the alphabet exists in the map, then remove it from the original list and add it to its corresponding queue in the map, `list.remove(element)` and `map.get('A').add(element)`
2. Iterate through the original list again and when an alphabet is encountered, add its corresponding queue from the map right after it.

I think this solution would work but I am not sure if it might fail for an edge case or if it is an optimal one(even though its complexity is O(n)).

Can anyone suggest a better alternative?

Comment: You could remember where the first of each "alphabet" is, so you wouldn't have to re-scan the list to find them.

Comment: This could be a bit complex to implement because the index will be changing whenever I would be deleting elements during the first iteration and adding elements during the second iteration.

Comment: Will the elements always be a either an integer or a single character followed by an integer?

Comment: @bliss Yes, that is correct

Comment: Why doesn't the output array start with 1..12? Is this not considered an alphabet?

Comment: The deleted elements will always come *after* the location they will get added to, so that isn't a problem.  And if you add them the queues in reverse order of the index they go to, that "complication" is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream API may be used in this case:

1. Build a `LinkedHashMap` grouping by letter prefix or number in each input element and collect the elements with equal prefixes into sorted set (or sorted list if duplicates are possible)
2. Get the values of the intermediate map of step 1 and join the sets/lists into a single list/array using `flatMap`

```java
String[] arr = {
    "1",  "2",  "3", "A1", "B1", "4", "B2",  "5",  "6", "C1", 
    "B3", "B4", "7", "8",  "9", "10", "A2", "A3", "11", "12", 
    "A4", "C2", "D1"
};

List<String> values = Arrays.stream(arr)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        s -> s.matches("[A-Z]\\d+") ? s.charAt(0) : s,
        LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.mapping(s -> s, Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new))
    )).values().stream()
    .flatMap(TreeSet::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(values);
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4, 4, 5, 6, C1, C2, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, D1]
```

Comment: This is a really great solution but I think I missed adding one information in my requirement that the final output should have the same order as the input which might not necessarily have ordered numbers. For example, the input might be [2, 1, 4....]. Nonetheless, I think replacing TreeSet with ArrayList should work.

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` will keep the insertion order of numeric/alphanumeric keys as is.  However, for duplicate numeric values the initial order may be broken and current implementation needs to be slightly amended to use indexes as keys for numeric elements.

Comment: Yes, I agree with the LinkedHashmap part now. But how can we use indexes as keys for numeric elements(since we are using stream)?

Comment: Using `IntStream.range(0, arr.length).boxed()` gives `Stream<Integer>` stream of indexes, so in groupingBy collector we'll have an index which may be used to retrieve `arr[i]`

Answer (score 1):

A two-phase approach that I believe is O(n) or close.

1. Analysis phase: Build your map as described in the question, but don’t remove anything from the array since this causes elements to be shifted and the O(n) to be broken.
2. Build a *new* list from the old one. For each element in the old list:

   1. If the element begins with a letter (alphabetic character), take out the list from the map, add all the elements to the new list *and remove the entry from the map*. If no entry was found in the map, it means that it has already been removed and added to the new list, so do nothing.
   2. Otherwise just add the element to the new list.
3. If required, write the contents of the new list back into the old list.

My first choice for the lists in the map would be `ArrayList`. If it matters, you can make your own performance measurements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach somewhat similar to what you described:

1. Initial iteration through the array:

   1. stores the indexes of all character strings in a Set<Integer>
   2. stores the indexes according to character in a Map<Character, List<Integer>>
2. Final iteration to construct the result array:

   - if the current index is contained in the previous set of character string indexes and the character has not been encountered yet, it inserts the relevant batch of Strings referred to in the Map<Character, List<Integer>>,
   - otherwise it is simply inserted into the result array.

```
public static String[] groupElements(String[] elements) {
    String[] groupedElements = new String[elements.length];
    Set<Integer> characterIndexes = new HashSet<>();
    Map<Character, List<Integer>> characterIndexesMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        char firstCharacter = elements[i].charAt(0);
        if (Character.isLetter(firstCharacter)) {
            characterIndexes.add(i);
            if (!characterIndexesMap.containsKey(firstCharacter)) {
                List<Integer> newCharacterIndexes = new ArrayList<>();
                newCharacterIndexes.add(i);
                characterIndexesMap.put(firstCharacter, newCharacterIndexes);
            }
            else {
                characterIndexesMap.get(firstCharacter).add(i);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < elements.length && j < elements.length; i++) {
        if (!characterIndexes.contains(i)) {
            groupedElements[j++] = elements[i];
        }
        else {
            char firstCharacter = elements[i].charAt(0);
            if (!characterIndexesMap.containsKey(firstCharacter)) continue;
            List<Integer> indexes = characterIndexesMap.get(firstCharacter);
            for (int k = 0; k < indexes.size(); k++) {
                groupedElements[j + k] = elements[indexes.get(k)];
            }
            j += indexes.size();
            characterIndexesMap.remove(firstCharacter);
        }
    }
    return groupedElements;
}
```

Edit: the solution above using the Streams API is simple to use and understand, but it has a significant performance cost compared to what I've posted. Use whichever depending on your application's needs.